# Is it unprofessional to mention your cover letter and resume are best viewed in Chrome?

Tags: resume, applications

I recently had to fill out a job application and I was required to provide a shareable link to my cover letter and resume on Google Drive, which read: "*Include your resume/CV (link to a Google Drive Document).*"

My issue is, when viewed in Chrome, the text is properly formatted, and looks professional, viewed in Firefox, the text is not properly formatted, and looks like I copied and pasted it without looking it over.

I have no idea what browser they will use to view my resume, and I don't want to them to get the wrong impression.

Is there a professional way to mention in my cover letter that my cover letter and resume are best viewed in Chrome?

Comment: The real question should be whether a resume that only looks right in one browser is going to seem professional. It won't.

Comment: Did they say (or strongly imply) that you must use Google Docs specifically, or are you allowed to use, e.g., a PDF file on Google Drive (which would not use Google Docs)?

Comment: It depends what job you are applying for. If you are a front-end developer then not being able to produce something that looks goo cross-browser will probably not impress

Comment: PDF stands for Portable Document Format. That's its very purpose, don't hesitate to use it.

Comment: Your cover letter and resume are swimming in a pool with lots of other cover letters - which don't have this limitation. Why handicap yourself this way?

Comment: This is what PDFs were invented for (probably)

Comment: @Smock it's the _portable_ document format, so yup :)

Comment: *"best viewed in ..."* will remind some of the bad old days of the early web and [Internet Explorer 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6) (or even [Netscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_(web_browser))).

Comment: I wonder what you're doing in your Google Doc that makes it not work well in Firefox. I primarily use Firefox and I've never had this problem.

Comment: Useless opinion: I think demanding a résumé as a link to a Google Drive document is unprofessional (for _at least_ the privacy implications). Don't put that in your cover letter though.

Comment: When I read “link to a Google Drive document” in this context, I immediately thought that they expect a PDF that's stored in Google Drive and shared by a link—*not* a Google Doc.

Comment: Just because you say "best viewed in Google Chrome" doesn't mean that a recruiter is likely to change their workflow if they are accustomed to using Firefox.

Comment: If you're applying for a web developer position then then browser-incompatibility is the absolute last thing you would want to point out about yourself.

Comment: Was your document originally created in Microsoft Word?  That would cause this nonsense.  It's really noticeable if you have edited your resume over the years with different versions of Word.

Comment: And if you’re not applying for a web developer position, then a résumé in HTML is a bad idea.  And if you still want to force a particular browser, why pick the one tied to NSA’s biggest competitor?

Comment: @marcelm Totally agree.  If I'm applying for a job, I do not intend for my resume to be broadcast to the world.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft to be fair, you can restrict the access on Google Drives to only those who have the link, or even only to specific people. Putting it on Drives doesn't mean it's public by default.

Comment: It's not unprofessional, but people reviewing resumes are firstly looking for what they can bin immediately. Don't tempt them.

Comment: I know a few backwards companies that still only use Internet Explorer...

Answer (score 355, accepted):

> Is there a professional way to mention in my cover letter that my cover letter and resume are best viewed in Chrome?

I would strongly suggest you **save your cover letter in PDF format** and share that via Google Drive.

That way the format will be preserved, the text will be aligned, etc., regardless of the way they decide to visualize it.

Mentioning that it would be better to view it in Chrome would be odd, and people may wonder why the restriction.

Comment: @Dan - most word processors can now open a PDF and convert into an editable document. It's probably more likely to work than requiring a conversion between office suites and versions (seeing as you don't know exactly what the recruiter has)

Answer (score 82):

> viewed in Firefox, the text is not properly formatted, and looks like I copied and pasted it without looking it over.

This means that your file **is not properly formatted**, probably as a result of copy-and-paste from various sources with different high-level styling that map similarly to fonts in Chome but map differently to fonts in Firefox. This kind of problem is endemic from the way WYSIWYG editors treat copy-and-paste, and short of digging deep into the hidden formatting, the only way to fix it is usually to select the whole block of text/whole document, click "remove formatting" or similar to make it all plain text, then manually add back the formatting you want.

Yes, it looks unprofessional. It looks even more unprofessional if you ask the reader to work around your unprofessional document preparation. Fix it.

For what it's worth, lots of articles published by "reputable" media outlets have the same unprofessional formatting problems in them these days.

Comment: Didn't test on Gdocs, but on Gmail using with Ctrl+Shift+V will paste the raw text without formatting. It comes handy for these exact situations.

Comment: @brasofilo this is also the case on thunderbird.

Comment: @brasofilo It's a good tip. I use it practically any time I cut and paste, and I find it works with most programs (or Ctrl+Alt+V if not).

Comment: If you right click, there is a usually an "paste without formatting" option in most Editors/email clients/etc.

Comment: @DanM.: Yep, that's a recent-ish addition and not always available, but a good option of it is. I just wish it were the default.

Comment: Copy and paste to notepad and back always works...

Answer (score 20):

If the recruiters explicitly demanded that you share your CV as a Google Doc, this suggests that they are accustomed to working with Google Docs and are probably already using the best browser for it. So I wouldn't be too bothered by imperfect Firefox rendering.

You could certainly create a PDF copy and send both links, but if they did mention Google Docs as opposed to Google Drive, this is likely to mean that they would prefer to easily copy and edit your text, which using PDF will make harder.

Comment: Upvote, but why would using PDF make copy/paste difficult?

Comment: Why would an employer need to edit an application? As for the copying, this is equally possible from PDF as long as there’s a text layer, which is default in the case of exported text documents.

Comment: @dessert, if it’s a recruitment agency, then chances are that they want to edit the cv before sending it to their clients. At minimum, they’ll want to remove personal contact details (because otherwise they’re giving away their "product"), but I understand they sometimes use a uniform format (header/footer, presumably) for all cvs. And recruitment agents aren’t necessarily great at using different file formats (I’ve seen some adverts requesting "Word" documents and thought "other formats are available").

Comment: @Mawg usually it doesn't but, for instance, a numbered list may be exported into PDF just as a text, with all information about the meaning of numbers lost. So if the recruiters would like to convert the information into a table, they'll have a harder time doing this with a PDF.

Comment: OP Clarified that they said: *"Include your resume/CV (link to a Google Drive Document)."* ... so they mentioned "Drive" and not "Docs".

Comment: *If the recruiters explicitly demanded that you share your CV as a Google Doc, this suggests that they are accustomed to working with Google Docs and are probably already using the best browser for it.* This makes no sense. Documents and web sites are supposed to work with browsers that support  standards. If they don't, it's a bug in the document or web site, not a reason for users to be forced to change browsers or stop using the web site.

Comment: @BenCrowell unless some company is developing both the application and a browser, in which case they might think to make it difficult to use other browsers to push theirs. But I'm just guessing...

Comment: Browsers support standards, but if the author has chosen to use a less popular font, which font is not on the reader’s computer, some other font will be chosen, often significantly affecting format.  Also, if format changes significantly on different fonts, that’s a clear sign the author does not know how to use his/her word processor efficiently.  Printing to PDF will hide the latter problem; it won’t always solve the first problem.  Only way to guarantee both is print it yourself and scan to an image.  Which the tech-savvy will view as unprofessional, and others tire of the long download.

Comment: By default when you share a Drive link, the recipient only has view (not edit) privileges. You have to explicitly grant any other permission.

Comment: @BenCrowell Google can't even make some of their own stuff look right in Chrome. Web UX in general peaked around 2003.

Comment: Don't work with recruiters who edit your resume.  It invariably ends up worse, and more than likely they'll change your contact info to theirs so that the company cannot reach out to you directly.  Let them cover their butts as far as referral fees another way.

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be with Google Docs compatibility with Firefox, but with some formatting in the particular document. The document can and should be fixed to work properly in any browser that can open the Google Docs application.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't go so far as to consider this unprofessional, though as an interviewer I might find it slightly odd. The only situation in which I would consider browser compatibility relevant to a resume would be if the material related to web design, which you have suggested is not the case.

As mentioned by others, the safest option is really to export it to a PDF, which would allow you to comply with the request and avoid the formatting issue all together. It would also avoid the situation in which the person reviewing it does not have Chrome on his or her machine and either declines to download it or does so with annoyance.

(I add my own answer here mostly to point out that not all people might react as negatively as the existing answers).

Answer (score -4):

I like DarkCygnus's answer but I have a different approach to this question.

I think the action of having people visit a public Google Docs would be unprofessional entirely. I think you'd get less calls that way because nobody wants to have to click links - especially in a security standpoint - to view resumes when you can easily just attach it to a email or online application. They'd have the same question I'd have, *"Why am I clicking links?"*

Why have people follow a link to view something they should be having in their hands?

My thought: share links to your personal website, or github account that's included in the resume/pdf. The company can view it if they please, but in my experience, they won't.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but they asked for it, it's part of the application process. They had a field where I could enter it.

Comment: Either you click a link, or you click an attachment. An attachment really is just a quick link to whatever you've attached anyway. Also, having a link for your resume is super convenient because you can update it for everywhere you've sent it without having to re-send it.

Comment: In terms of security, there's just as much chance as there being a virus in an attachment as there is in a link. Especially since you can see where the link is pointing to (in this case google drive, which has it's own security scanners)

Comment: It states in the question "I was required to provide a shareable link". So it is not their choice but a requirement of the application.

Comment: @ThomasBowen - You are correct!